# Python deleting local variables through a loop

Tags: python

I wrote the following code in middle of a function to delete all variables except few.

```
dontDelete = ['Cat','Dog']
for vi in dir(): #'Cat','Dog','Pig','Elephant','Lion'
    if vi in dontDelete:
        continue
    else:
        del locals()[vi]
```

But it doesn't delete any variables even though it goes to the `del locals()[vi]` statement

Edit1: I am running out of memory in middle of the function. So, I thought about removing the 100's of variables I have locally in the function. I wrote the snippet above only to show what I am seeking on doing.

Edit2: can someone explain why negative votes on this question. Is there an obvious solution that I am missing.

Edit3: I am not able to create another function in middle of what I am doing. So, I want to try the delete variables option

Comment: Why are you doing this? What's the actual problem you're attempting to solve?

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is almost certainly solved by the automatic memory management system.

Comment: Also, you really should have checked the [`locals` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals).

Comment: If you run out of memory in the middle of a function, you probably don't want to band-aid that by deleting variables.  Instead, you probably want to be using subfunctions, and by being more cautious about how much memory you use in the first place.

Comment: Deleting miscellaneous variables is not a fix for memory errors, and deleting from the `locals()` dictionary won't do it anyway. From the docs: "**Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."

Comment: I don't know about the other downvote, but my downvote is because you didn't even check the documentation for the function you're relying on. If you did, you would have seen the warning telling you that modifying `locals` doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess the idea of trying to do manual memory management in Python because you have a function that have more than 100 variables just doesn't seem right. There is no obvious solution because this problem is not supposed to happen in the first place.

Comment: "I am not able to create another function in middle of what I am doing." Of course you can. It may be harder than you'd like, but trying to force Python to violate it's design is not particularly easy.

Comment: It is not necessary to delete variables from your namespace to free up memory; simply assigning them some other value (e.g. `None`) will work, assuming there are no other references to the large object you're trying to free. (And if there are other references, deleting them from your locals wouldn't help anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

[`locals()` is a view on the locals, mutating it is not recommended and provides no guarantees as to whether the "real" values are changed or not.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), per the note from the docs:

> Note: The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

The correct solution is usually to refactor your function, so all the stuff you want to delete are local variables in a separate function, and the stuff you want to keep is returned by that function. Python will clean the locals for you when the subfunction returns, so only the return values are kept; if there are reference cycles in that local scope that *must* be freed immediately, you can explicitly call [`gc.collect()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect) after the function returns to force a full cycle collection, but that's usually not necessary.